# Ionic Modal: No component factory found

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'd like to open a modal in Ionic:

```
export class TexteditorComponent {
   function showFormulaEditor() {
     this.modalCtrl.create({
       component: FormulaCreatorComponent
     }).then(m => m.present());
   }
}
```

However, when this code is executed, I get the following error:

```
Error: "Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for FormulaCreatorComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

TexteditorComponent and FormulaCreatorComponent are registered in a texteditor.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [TexteditorComponent, FormulaCreatorComponent],
  entryComponents: [TexteditorComponent, FormulaCreatorComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [TexteditorComponent, FormulaCreatorComponent]
})
export class TexteditorModule { }
```

The texteditor.module.ts is imported in exercise.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    TexteditorModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [ExercisePage, PatternedInputComponent]
})
export class ExercisePageModule {
  constructor() {
    console.log("ExercisePageModule init");
  }
}
```

The ExercisePage loads the TexteditorComponent using its selector:

```
<app-texteditor [(ngModel)]="exercise.Exercise"></app-texteditor>
```

That all works fine, the TexteditorComponent is rendered properly.

Only the modal won't open.
I logged my modalCtrl in showFormulaEditor():
[image: Factory for FormulaCreatorComponent exists]
There definitely is a factory for FormulaCreatorComponent.

However, the following Code returns undefined:

```
modalCtrl.resolver._factories.get(FormulaCreatorComponent)
```

Despite this, I can add the FormulaCreatorComponent to the TexteditorComponent with its selector:

```
<app-formulacreator></app-formulacreator>
```

that works without problems.

Comment: add `FormulaCreatorComponent` to `exports` array

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same error with FormulaCreatorComponent added to exports. I only use that component in TexteditorComponent, which is registered in the same module.

Comment: You imported `TextEditorModule` in `app.module.ts` no?

Comment: No, I added the app.module to the question

Comment: Add TextEditorModule to imports array of app.module.ts error will be solved

Comment: add entryComponent in app.module.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it...
In texteditor.component.ts I imported FormulaCreatorComponent with the following Line:

```
import { FormulaCreatorComponent } from './formulacreator/formulacreator.component.js';
```

Obviously, the `.js` is incorrect. My IDE (Visual Studio Code) recognized it anyway and led me to the correct destination when I clicked "Open Definition".